# How to add 12spaces to the next line after the string match in shell?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file called `config.toml`. I am doing the string match with `runc.options` as highlighted in the image. I need to insert a string `"Systemdgroup = true"` after 12 spaces. I tried the below command, which works, but used *manual* white 12 spaces. How it can be achieved in another way?

```
sed -e "/runc.options/a\            SystemdCgroup = true" /etc/containerd/config.toml
```

[image]

Instead of typing literally 12 spaces, anything like `/s+12` work?

Comment: Please consider posting the actual text of the file rather than an image of it. We can't do much with a picture, but we could test that our solutions worked if we had the file itself to test it on.

Comment: It would seem like somebody acchieved something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072875/insert-with-sed-n-repeated-characters)

Comment: There are tools specifically made to work with TOML files. Using a TOML-aware utility would be more convenient than `sed` and would also ensure that the output is still valid TOML.  Without a file to test on, however, it isn't easy to help.

Comment: Yeah, but I can not directly edit the file, i have to go through the script. It is the backend script that is responsible for inserting the value with 12spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do this directly with REGEX patterns, but you may (ab)use `printf`'s option for left-patting with spaces and an empty string:

```
sed "/pattern/a$(printf '\%12s')SystemCgroup = .../" file
```

Note that the percent sign needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used your command but it is just going to the next line but not taking 12 spaces.
 sed "/runc.options/a$(printf "%12s")SystemCgroup = true" /etc/containerd/config.toml


          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
          base_runtime_spec = ""
          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
SystemCgroup = true

Comment: What does `printf "%12s"` return as command when run directly in the shell?

Comment: If i directly pass printf "%12s", it is taking 12spaces. When i run along with the original command which you sent doesnt take 12spaces, it goes to next line.

Comment: This is how it looks:
[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `unix@BDC8-LX-CVZ52X2:~/12space$ printf "%12s"
            unix@BDC8-LX-CVZ52X2:~/12space$
unix@BDC8-LX-CVZ52X2:~/12space$ sed "/ath2/a$(printf "%12s")SystemCgroup = true" space
ath1
ath2
SystemCgroup = true
ath3
ath4
ath5
unix@BDC8-LX-CVZ52X2:~/12space$`

Comment: sed "/ath2/a$(printf '\%12s')newdata" space worked for me. '\' was missing earlier. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Ath_New you are right, this needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Using the TOML parser `tomlq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```bsh
tomlq -t '.plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options.SystemdCgroup |= true' config.toml
```

Use `tomlq` with its `--in-place` (or `-i`) option to make an in-place edit.

The expression used with `tomlq` above is a `jq` expression (`tomlq` is a `jq` wrapper) which sets the specific key in the document's structure to the value `true`.

Note that the spacing in the document does not matter for the validity of the document structure.

---

In general, with `sed`, if you want to insert a line of text at the same indentation depth as a previous line, consider reusing the indentation of that previous line.

```
/^\([[:blank:]]*\)\[.*runc\.options\].*/ {
    h
    s//\1  SystemdCgroup = true/
    H
    g
}
```

This `sed` script matches the specific section label we're looking for and remembers the number of blanks preceding the `[` on that line.  It saves a copy of the line in the hold space, replaces the line in the buffer with our new data, using `\1` to insert the original indentation.  Then appends the buffer to the hold space (which inserts a newline character) and fetches the hold space into the editing buffer to be printed.

Note, however, that `sed` and similar line-oriented tools are often inadequate for working with structured document formats such as TOML, YAML, JSON, and XML. These formats are not always line-delimited as they may require a particular encoding of data.

Comment: to use this command, i need to pass tomlq installation but it is been restricted not to pass any install command to the current script. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ath_New It seems as if you only read the top half of my answer.

Comment: yeah, i read only first part. Can you please explain me the h and H ? I did not completely understand the code.

Comment: @Ath_New Those are standard `sed` editing commands. `h` replaces the hold space with the current buffer, and `H` appends the current buffer to the hold space with a newline character as a delimiter between the old and the added strings. The `g` gets the hold space into the editing buffer. That is more or less what I already wrote in my answer.